# How to print i and i+1 in a for-loop?

Tags: android, for-loop

I have an array full of names. Im using a for-loop to print my names but the problem is that I want to print 2 names: `i(the name) and i+1 (the next name)`. you may not get what I said, look at my code:

## My code:

"text" is my textview and "people" is the array:

```
people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add("Sam");
people.add("John");
people.add("Kim");
people.add("Edison");

for (int i=0; i< people.size(); i = i+2) {
text.append(people.get(i) + " with " + people.get(i+1));
}
```

### the problem is it prints this:

(these are the names in the array : "Kim","John","Sam","Edison")

Kim with Kim Sam with Sam

#### instead of this :

Kim with John Sam with Edison

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in your code. Are you sure that the output is wrong? Or maybe your array contains "Kim","Kim","John","John","Sam",...

Comment: Could you show us the array you are using?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and its working well.

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);

String[] people = {"Kim","John","Sam","Edison"};

for (int i=0; i< people.length; i = i+2) {
    tv.append(people[i] + " with " + people[i+1]+"\n");
}
```

If you are using List then

```
List<String> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add("Kim");
people.add("John");
people.add("Sam");
people.add("Edison");

for (int i=0; i< people.size(); i = i+2) {
    tv.append(people.get(i) + " with " + people.get(i+1)+"\n");
}
```

**Output:**

> Kim with John
>   Sam with Edison

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working for me please check if your array is okay.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
     
     String[] names = {"Vikas","Kumar","Rajat","Ghator"};
     
     for (int i=0; i< names.length; i = i+2) {
     
        System.out.println(names[i] + " with " + names[i+1]);   
     }
     
 }
```

}

prints:

> Vikas with Kumar
>
> Rajat with Ghator

Comment: Im using Arraylist<>() like this: [people = new Arraylist<>()]  then i add the names like this: people.add("kim")